# Cannot export data into sd card

Tags: android

I wanted to export the data from my application to sdcard on a click and I am performing the below function to do so, but I am not able to do it. It doesn't execute the if statement and it goes out of the loop without executing.

```
private void exportDB() {
    try {

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File sd=new File("/storage/9016-4EF8/ppt");

        if (sd.canWrite()) {

            File currentDBPath = getDatabasePath(Constants.DB_NAME);
                    String backupDBPath = "ppt";

            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDBPath).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

I am new to this and developing an application with sqlite

Comment: Do you have WRITE permission in manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have included the above in my manifest

Comment: if your device version above marshmallow than check run time permission  is given or not ?

Comment: Given the permission already@mehul